# Setting a Visual C++ breakpoint at a given file and line number

Tags: debugging, visual-c++

I know I want a breakpoint at `foo.c:234` in a library that my app is using.  I can input breakpoints by typing in a function name on the Breakpoints window: New-->Function Breakpoint... .  I know I could hunt for the file, open it, scroll to the line, and click it.  But I just want to type the `foo.c:234` I already know.

It seems like a trivial ask but ten minutes on Google isn't finding it!

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022  on Windows 11.

Comment: If you have the file open and in the foreground in Visual Studio, you can double-click on the line number in the text editor's status bar and type the line number to go to that line.

Comment: Yes, Spencer.  The file is however not open, and please assume that it is not convenient to get to.

Comment: Even through the Solution Explorer?

Comment: It's in a library that's not part of this solution but that is compiled with debug enabled.

Comment: And what should happen if the file you specify does not contain a statement at the line number you specify (for example, if `foo.c:234` happens to be an empty line)?

Comment: I could tell you what would happen, if I could figure out how to try it.  However, in this case, I know there is code on that line as the library in question is logging it in the Output window using __FILE__ and __LINE__ macros.